# How to split a tuple into sub-tuples based on a condition in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list like this `[1,2,1,1,2,3,3]`.
I want to separate this tuple into sub-tuples according to:

```
[1,2,1,1] [2,1,1,2] [3,3]
```

So the condition to separate the vector is when the first number of the tuple repeats itself for the last time.

How can I do this?

Comment: you speak about tuple and you show list?

Comment: @Frenchy I'm not sure it matters here, I guess any iterable should do. Anyway, I fixed it ;)

Comment: i dunno if this expression exists in english but I nitpick....

Answer (score 2):

You can read the elements and collect the first and last index per element as you go.

Then slice your list accordingly:

```
l = [1,2,1,1,2,3,3]

d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(l): # for each value in the input
    if v not in d:      # if the value was not yet seen
        d[v] = [i, i+1] # record its position and the next in d
    else:               # if the value was already seen
        d[v][1] = i+1   # update its last position (+1 for inclusive slicing)

out = {k: l[slice(*v)] for k,v in d.items()}
```

output (here as a dictionary):

```
{1: [1, 2, 1, 1],
 2: [2, 1, 1, 2],
 3: [3, 3]}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

a simple program:

```
l = (1,2,1,1,2,3,3)
r=[]
for i in set(l):
    li = len(l) - 1 - l[::-1].index(i)   #last index of item
    lf = l.index(i)                      #first index of item
    r.append((l[lf:li+1]))

print(r)
```

result:

```
[(1, 2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Note that the larger is the list and the greater is the diversity of numbers, the higher are the chances that you need to read it again in depth. On average, I expect it to be slower than a linear read.  This might prove very fast if you have a very large list with few numbers and first/last indices close to the edges, though.

Comment: yes of course, its just a solution for beginner...

Comment: It depends on the data, as I said there are case where it is more efficient ;) (+1)